# Leading zeros master code disappear when retrieving documents

Tags: php

I have 2 contracts with master codes, 1 is for example '13' and is placed in folder '13' and another one has for example '00000013' (with leading zeros) and is placed in folder '00000013'. But if we read the master codes, we lose the leading zeroes, so that we get to see the wrong documents. How do I get the document with master code '00000013' read from the correct folder?

```
if (isset($_GET['companycode']) && isset($_GET['mastercode'])) {
    $FileRetreiverType = FileRetreiverTypeEnums::Tables;
    $Code = $_GET['companycode'];
    $Code2 = $_GET['mastercode'];
    $Year = $_GET['year'];
    $retreiver = new FileRetreiver($Year, $FileRetreiverType, $Code, $Code2);
    $response .= $retreiver->GetResponse($ReturnFormat);
}

class FileRetreiver {
    public function __construct($year, $retreiverType, $id, $id2 = '') {
        $this->FileRetreiverType = $retreiverType;
        $this->Id = $id;
        $this->Id2 = $id2;
        $this->Year = $year;
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

The folder on the internet is built up in the following way:
For example, you have a folder: ../2017/Tables/321/13/
and a folder: ../2017/Tables/321/00000013/

```
$Response = "../". $this->Year. "/ Tables /". $this->Id. "/". $this->Id2. "/";
```

Comment: Are you sure the master code is sent properly? It looks like conversion to Int somewhere.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't expose any reason for the behaviour you described. Most probably you convert the value of `$_GET['master code']` to `int` in the code you didn't post.

Comment: you can typecast variable into string and then check it then it will not lose zero.

Comment: It has to be a string. My knowledge about php small.

Comment: And how do I solve it. I don't know...

Comment: Post the minimal code sending the request.

Comment: Side note: I'd advice against GET parameter names with a space in them in order to avoid encoding. In other words, I'd turn `master code` into `master-code` or `mc`.

Comment: As @kabanus correctly pointed out: we still need to see the code that is sending the GET data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this will not convert it into int datatype

```
if (isset ($_GET ['company code']) && isset ($_GET ['master code']))
{
$FileRetreiverType = FileRetreiverTypeEnums :: Tables;
$Code = "$_GET ['company code']";
$Code2 = (string)"$_GET ['master code']";
$Year = $_GET ['year'];
$retreiver = new FileRetreiver ($Year, $FileRetreiverType, $Code, $Code2);
$response. = $retreiver-> GetResponse ($ReturnFormat);
}
```

Comment: And you don't have to change this command $this->Id2 = $id2; ?

Comment: no if database have string in it it will return string

Comment: $this->Id2 what is it returning?

Comment: @Xitas, how were you able to test the code without knowing how OP is sending the data?

Comment: i didn't use OP to send data.the problem is getting data so i checked if it was sending it right or not. getting file is another problem